# Storing PDF files on a MySQL server Intelligently

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, search, phpmyadmin

I've been tasked with creating a search system that will help users to navigate through multiple 1000+ page pdf files. However, these files will first have to be put on a MySQL DB. The issue that i'm currently having is how do I store these PDF files on the DB and assign the relevant PDF headers to the DB.

**Example:**

Adding each Part/Header/Section/Subsection individually on the DB in different tables.

Would this all have to be manually entered? Bare in mind we are talking 100,000s  pages + of PDF.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to store PDFs in a database. Rethink your approach.

Comment: Files belong on the filesystem, databases are for data. Store the pdfs on the filesystem and store the paths on the db if you must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better to store some meta data in the database, and store the location of the PDF file.

i.e. a table called 'documents' may have the following fields:
id,path,keywords,category

The path would be: /some/location/to/my/pdf/file.pdf

The keywords could be; 'pdf1, what is a pdf, some search text'

This will allow you to store the pdf files.

Alternatively you could use something like Google - they allow you to use their search technology. It used to be in the form of a 'google yellow box' but I believe it's now part of their cloud stuff!

HTH

Comment: The problem I have is that these pdfs are mainly going to be searched by external clients who don't always know "x,y,z" what they are looking for. My search system has to be able to point the user in the direction of the relevant pdf/pdf page they are looking for. These documents ate also updated regularly, usually every 6 months or less meaning standard pdf links have little survivability

Comment: With regard to different versions, i would suggest adding another column, version. This would ensure you keep historic record of the PDFs for auditing purposes.

Comment: In terms of the search content; there are several "pdf2text" libraries. But I'm not sure that's the approach you want as you're then storing all that data in the database. I'd definitely suggest looking at Google search Appliance :)